# Having problems reading google maps marker data from Google Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime database, where I store Google Maps Marker data. It looks like this: [Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grexq.png)

My application has the option to add your own marker to the database, my problem is that my application only reads the info from Studio 1 and T1, not from the random key added by .push(). when i add a marker via the app. Any ideas on how to get it to read the marker info that is under the random key? My code looks as follows:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mProfileRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Studios");
ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Button addAStudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addAStudio);
    addAStudio.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Rent.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    LatLng  Copenhagen = new LatLng(55.67, 12.56);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Copenhagen, 18));
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //get marker info from Firebase Database and add to map
    addMarkersToMap(googleMap);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    if(mChildEventListener != null)
        mProfileRef.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    super.onStop();
}

private void addMarkersToMap(final GoogleMap map){

    mChildEventListener = mProfileRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {



        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                FirebaseMarker marker = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class);
                String StudioName = marker.getStudioName();
                String StudioAdress = marker.getStudioAddress();
                String StudioDescription = marker.getStudioDescription();
                double latitude = marker.getLatitude();
                double longitude = marker.getLongitude();
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(location)
                        .title(StudioName)
                        .snippet(StudioAdress)
                        .snippet(StudioDescription))
                        .showInfoWindow();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    return false;
}
```

And

```
public class FirebaseMarker {

public String studioName;
public String studioDescription;
public String studioAddress;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;


//required empty constructor
public FirebaseMarker() {
}

public FirebaseMarker(String studioName, String studioDescription, String studioAdress, double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.studioName = studioName;
    this.studioDescription = studioDescription;
    this.studioAddress = studioAdress;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getStudioName() {
    return studioName;
}

public void setStudioName(String studioName) {
    this.studioName = studioName;
}

public String getStudioDescription() {
    return studioDescription;
}

public void setStudioDescription(String studioDescription) {
    this.studioDescription = studioDescription;
}

public String getStudioAddress() {
    return studioAddress;
}

public void setStudioAddress(String studioAddress) {
    this.studioAddress = studioAddress;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}
```

}

and finally where add a new marker to the database:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rent);
    saveStudio = findViewById(R.id.saveStudio);
    studioNameTextField = findViewById(R.id.studioNameTextField);
    studioInfoTextField = findViewById(R.id.studioInfoTextField);
    studioAdressTextField = findViewById(R.id.studioAdressTextField);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDataBaseRef = mDatabase.getReference("Studios");
    saveStudio = findViewById(R.id.saveStudio);


    saveStudio.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Map<String, FirebaseMarker> newStudioAdd = new HashMap<>();

                newStudioAdd.put(studioNameTextField.getText().toString(),
                        new FirebaseMarker(
                                studioNameTextField.getText().toString(),
                                studioInfoTextField.getText().toString(),
                                studioAdressTextField.getText().toString(),
                                53.669115, 12.560311
                        )
                );

                mDataBaseRef.push().setValue(newStudioAdd);

          Intent intent = new Intent(Rent.this, MapsActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

as of now the latitude and longitude are hardcoded, as i want it to read the markers before i continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `Studio 1` and `T1` have different paths than the `T2`. As I see in your database schema, your `T2` as an extra child (`-LH-3 ... GbsF`) which is generated by the `push()` method. In order to display all those objects correctly, you need to have the same paths for all objects. So you can achieve this, either by adding `Studio 1` and `T1` in the same way, using the `push()` method or by adding the `T2` without using the `push()` method.

```
FirebaseMarker firebaseMarker = new FirebaseMarker(
    studioNameTextField.getText().toString(),
    studioInfoTextField.getText().toString(),
    studioAdressTextField.getText().toString(),
    53.669115, 12.560311);
mDataBaseRef.push().setValue(firebaseMarker);
```

Assuming that the `Studios` node is a direct child of your Firebase database, here is how you can add the markers on the map:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference studiosRef = rootRef.child("Studios");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            FirebaseMarker marker = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class);
            String StudioName = marker.getStudioName();
            String StudioAdress = marker.getStudioAddress();
            String StudioDescription = marker.getStudioDescription();
            double latitude = marker.getLatitude();
            double longitude = marker.getLongitude();
            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(location)
                    .title(StudioName)
                    .snippet(StudioAdress)
                    .snippet(StudioDescription))
                    .showInfoWindow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
studiosRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: I just removed Studio 1 and T1 and added two new studios using the push method. None of the three show up now. I think the randomly generated key (extra child) somehow messes things up.

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behaviour. You are trying now to read the data from a wrong reference. Try the other solution. Add `Studio 1` and `T1` as it was before and then try to add again `T2`, without the push() method, are now all three objects correctly displayed?

Comment: The problem with not using the .push() method it overwrites the entire database. So i need to read the data from the different references with random generated keys.

Comment: In this case use the `push()` method but don't use that Map anymore, just use `mDataBaseRef.push().setValue(firebaseMarker);` as in my updated answer.

Comment: Using your answer it stores the data under the random generated key from the push method, without the extra child, but it still doesn't add the markers to the map.

Comment: That's a correct schema. I'll write some code so you can add markers on the map.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works now! I had to make it ds.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class); instead of FirebaseMarker marker = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class); though.